# How can I turn on visibility of hidden files permanently?

Tags: macos, terminal, ventura

Using Ventura, I can turn on hidden files using the shortcut

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

How can I set this permanently?

Comment: Thanks, that answer is what I was looking for.